# What is different between authorize_security_group and authorize_security_group_ingress aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I can't find document about `authorize_security_group()` method, only for `ingress` and `egress` ones.

Can someone give a quick brief if I use `authorize_security_group()` method, what will it default to? `ingress` or `egress`?

Comment: Do you have some documentation that says `authorize_security_group()` exists? I don't think there is such a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingress.

You are authorizing a security group for your ingress rule. To add a security group to an egress rule you must use authorize_security_group_egress().

Consider switching to boto3. The functions above are boto which is an older library. All the major development activity is in boto3.

Comment: Outbound rules or egress rules seem pretty useless when they come with restrictions as a firewall on instances, use `Network ACLs` of VPCs instead. Default to `ingress` is correct.

Comment: Security Groups are "smart" meaning that they will allow the outbound connection port based upon an inbound connection. NACS are dumb and you must specify which ports are open both inbound and outbound. Also remember that Security Groups protect network adapters (ENI), NACLS protect the entire subnet (VPC).

Comment: I don't see any practical case for `egress` sg down to more specific to fence ec2 instances in between private subnets and dmz zones.

Comment: @TuyenPham - I don't understand your comment.